# Explanation required of the following definition:

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

This is a definition I encountered in a paper. I hope someone will be able to help me understand it. The authors assume a Frenet curve $\alpha(s)$ on a 3-D Riemannian Manifold as any non-geodesic unit speed-curve that satisfies the Frenet Equations using the Levi-Civita Connection $\nabla_s$, $s$ being the arc length parameter of the curve $\alpha$.
Then they give the following definition(part of which is given):
Let $α(s)$ be a Frenet curve in a 3-dimensional Riemannian
manifold M and $\lbrace T_α,N_α,B_α\rbrace$ the Frenet frame of α. Consider a surface $X_{N_\alpha}$ defined by
$$X_{N_\alpha}(s, t) = exp_{α(s)}(tN_α(s)).$$

I am interested in understanding the nature of this surface.

I presume that as defined in the same paper: $exp_p(v)=\gamma_v(1)$ for any $v\in T_p(M)$,where $\gamma_v$ is a constant speed geodesic on M defined on $[0,\infty)$ such that $\gamma_v(0)=p,\gamma_v'(0)=v$ ,
the above surface could be written as $X_{N_\alpha}(s,t)=\gamma_{N_\alpha(s)}(t)$, but that is not helping me much.

I would also like to know why the definition of the exponential map here requires the geodesic to be of constant speed.

Comment: For the second question, are you asking for intuition? The exponential map is intuitively where a point should go if it were to be "flicked"--where the natural path would take it. The most natural way for it to go down this path is the constant speed paramaterization.

Comment: Well, I sort of get your idea, but can you elaborate on what you mean by "flicking"?Do you mean to say the most feasible path that the point would travel along when left free to move??And isnt an exponential map sort of a parametrisation of a Manifold in terms of the tangent space at a point. Thanks

Comment: It's called a Frenet ruled surface.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please direct me to some literature on this? A Google search did not help me.

Comment: http://www.idosi.org/wasj/wasj6(5)/18.pdf

Comment: Some pictures of ruled surfaces: http://public.beuth-hochschule.de/~schwenk/Lehrgebiete/skoric/Welcome.html

Comment: Sorry for complaining, but that paper doesnt seem to help much.Thanks for the links though.Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Concerning your question on parametrization: go for “normal coordinates."